# How to read a number in specific line and increase by one

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that can increase the amount of lines in a .ini file.
The files looks like this (not the complete file):

```
[IndexFile]

;*** DATABASE FILES ***
FileSpec_1=C:\Solid4.2\solid.1 1000m
FileSpec_2=C:\Solid4.2\solid.2 1000m
FileSpec_3=C:\Solid4.2\solid.3 1000m
;
; SOLID uses by default 'solid.db' as the first database file,
```

I want my program to read amount of lines containing "FileSpec" in the file and ask the user how many lines he/she wan't in total. User input amount ex: 8. Then the program writes five additional lines to the file.

This is what I have so far:

```
int count = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(16).Count(line => line.Contains("FileSpec"));
Console.WriteLine(("There are ") + (count) + (" Filespec-lines in the file, how many do you want in total?"));
int antall22=(int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int linestoadd = antall22 - count;
```

So, "linestoadd" is the amount of lines that should be written to the file.
How can I write amount of lines to the file and also increase the numbers after the underscore so that it increases to two(10+) and three(100+) digits numbers?

Comment: It's not clear what lines you are adding should contain

Comment: They should contain: "FileSpec_3=C:\Solid4.2\solid.3 1000m" only the number(3) should increase for each line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
for(int i=count+1; i<= antall22; i++)
{
     lines.Add(string.Format("FileSpec_{0}=C:\Solid4.2\solid.{0} 1000m",i));
}
File.AppendAllLines(filepath,lines);
```

for your input it will add 5 lines to your file:

```
FileSpec_4=C:\Solid4.2\solid.4 1000m
FileSpec_5=C:\Solid4.2\solid.5 1000m
FileSpec_6=C:\Solid4.2\solid.6 1000m
FileSpec_7=C:\Solid4.2\solid.7 1000m
FileSpec_8=C:\Solid4.2\solid.8 1000m
```

It will always add consecutive numbers in `FileSpec_{number}` even if they will be multiple digits long

Explaination:

```
for(int i=count+1; i<= antall22; i++)
```

means that initially `i` = count+1 <- next number of line and will proceed up to `antall22` by 1 (i++). In every iteration `i` is `count+1+numberofiteration`, so it will be:

> 1st iteration: i=4
>
> 2nd iteration: i=5
>
> so on...

Comment: Thanks!
That looks much less complicated than I expected.
Sadly tho I'm not very skilled yet, so I don't fully understand what you do with the for(int i=count+1; i<= antall22; i++) You say that if i <= antall22 then you do i++ ?

I'm getting error: "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"

Comment: @user2928068 about error: see edit, i should be after coma :) I'll edit my answer with explaination of this loop

Comment: Thanks again for your'e time and help.
Now the lines are added, but the previous lines are deleted. I need the existing lines to still be there. Also I forgot to add that there are some more lines before and after the actual fileSpec lines. I'll update first post. Sorry for being unclear..

Comment: @user2928068 why have you unchecked my answer?

Comment: Yeah, as I need the already existing lines not to be deleted. Now I get an empty file with just the new lines written to it.

Comment: @user2928068 change to new code using `AppendAllLines` it will append them and keep exisitng ones